# Sliding Text Over Image: How to Keep Footer Below All Elements

Tags: html, css

This html/css (see result at http://jsfiddle.net/0x4u00we/embedded/result/) behaves as intended, except when the page gets narrow enough that the "notice" and "footer" div overlap; the desired behaviour in this case is that the footer slides down accordingly.

I realize that the absolute positioning of the #notice takes it out of the flow and there is likely only javascript that can lower #footer artificially.

However, my objective keep this in 100% html/css. I have attempted many other html structures and css settings (floats, etc). All suggestions welcome. Thx.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">

         html {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        body {
            margin: 10px;
        }

        #paintsplatter {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 1000px;
            padding-bottom: 25px;
            /*overflow: hidden;*/
        }

        #psimg {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            z-index: -2;
        }

        #notice {
            position: absolute;
            top: 55%;
            left: 7%;
            width: 43%;
            margin-left: 30px;
            font-size: 12pt;
            font-weight: 600;
            z-index: 0;
        }

        #footer {
            position: relative;
            margin-top: 20px;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 12pt;
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.65);
            z-index: 1;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="paintsplatter">
            <img id="psimg" src="http://i62.tinypic.com/dp8cw1.jpg">
            <div id="notice">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's quite a problem.
If you use *#notice* as *position: absolute*, you won't have a fix.
Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">

         html {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        body {
            margin: 10px;
        }

        #paintsplatter {
            background: url(http://i62.tinypic.com/dp8cw1.jpg) center no-repeat;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-clip: border-box;
            background-size: contain;
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 1000px;
            padding-bottom: 25px;
            /*overflow: hidden;*/
        }

        #notice {
            position: relative;
            padding-top: 40%;
            padding-left: 7%;
            width: 43%;
            margin-left: 30px;
            font-size: 12pt;
            font-weight: 600;
            z-index: 0;
        }

        #footer {
            position: relative;
            margin-top: 20px;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 12pt;
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.65);
            z-index: 1;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="paintsplatter">
            <div id="notice">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Fabio. Setting the image as the background fulfills all my requirements while solving the issue. Made a minor adjustment to the background-position.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, take your footer out of the `#paintsplatter` div, you don't need it there and it will only cause issues the way you have it now.

Once you do that, just a few changes in `#notice` div will make it:

```
#notice {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 25%;
    left: 7%;
    width: 43%;
    margin-left: 30px;
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-weight: 600;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

[See fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/s6sLL4j5/)

**Explanation:**

Since you want to prevent the text to find the BOTTOM of document, then it's easier to use `bottom` property instead of `top`. Then the text will behave better since no matter how hard the footer pushes the content, that text will always be 25% of the containing element's size above. Of course, in this type of layouts, you'll need to adjust at lower screens, there's no way to avoid it because it's inherent to your approach, but you can use media queries and add more width, lower the `bottom` property value, use pixels, whatever

Comment: Thank you Fabio. First, I moved `#footer` out of `#paintsplatter` as you correctly highlighted (a remnant of some of my other tests). However, I am looking for a solution that keeps the top of the text in the non-coloured area of the picture, i.e. starting in the lower half of the picture. It is correctly expanding below the lower edge of the picture; what I am trying to achieve is to have the `#footer` slide down accordingly.

Comment: even easier, just change that `bottom:25%` to `bottom: 5%;` . The idea of the fiddle is that you play with the values and see how it works so you understand by example, but the code I gave you is a basic approach for your given scenario and works more or less the same in every similar situation with just some adjustments